# SAS Method of Using the Closest Date

Tags: sql, sas

I'm looking for a method to use the closest date in SAS. I've seen many examples online, but due to their complexity and my inexperience with SAS I am unable to tailor them to my needs appropriately. The solution would preferably be in SQL (via proc sql) for consistency, but if the same task is easier to accomplish in SAS code then that is acceptable as well.

The table I'm querying (Table B) has data that looks similar to this:

```
    ID        Contract   Plan Code     From       Thru 
  8516515      S5000        000      1/1/2013   2/28/2013 
  8516515      S6100        010      1/1/2012  12/31/2012
  8516515      H3565        025      1/1/2011  12/31/2011
```

The table (Table A) that I'm inner joining to the above data looks similar to this:

```
    ID           PA
  8516515    ITPNB010412
```

The date that I'm using to query Table B is assigned in a macro variable called `date_of_report` and in the case of the example above (Table B) `date_of_report` is `"11Apr2013"d`.

I am looking to make the code pull line #1 in Table B and not the others. There should be no cases where we have to round up a specific timeframe... only pick the most recent eligible line.

Comment: If there is a MAX() function is SAS then you probably can use it to select max(date_of_report)...

Comment: @art There is a MAX() function available in PROC SQL, but would I use it on date_of_report? I figured I'd use it on the 'Thru' column of Table B. I did try that as: `case when &date_of_report not between TableB.FromDate and TableB.Thrudate then
 max(TableB.Thrudate)
end as 'Thru'n,` as part of my select - would that instead somehow go in the where statement?

Comment: Can you be a bit more clear on your requirements?  You want, specifically, which row from TableB.  You want first the row where the value in &date_of_report. is between From and Thru, and if that is not possible then you want the date that is closest to &date_of_report but always before?

Comment: @Joe Yes, those are exactly the requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is pretty easy to solve in SAS.  There are two fairly straightforward solutions, depending on whether you need to solve this for a single record in table A or potentially for multiple records (multiple IDs, for example).

```
data tableB;
informat from Thru MMDDYY10.;
input ID        Contract   $ Plan_Code     From       Thru;
datalines;
8516515      S5000        000      1/1/2013   2/28/2013 
8516515      S6100        010      1/1/2012  12/31/2012
8516515      H3565        025      1/1/2011  12/31/2011
;;;;
run;

data tableA;
input  ID           PA $;
datalines;
8516515    ITPNB010412
;;;;
run;
```

Given those tableA and tableB, here is solution 1 - works when tableA is only one ID.

```
proc sort data=tableB;
by ID thru;
run;

%let dateofreport='12APR2013'd;
data tableC;
set tableB;
by ID thru;
retain a_set;
if first.ID then a_set=0;
if from le &dateofreport. le thru then do;
  set tableA;
  a_set=1;
end;
else call missing(PA);
if not(a_set) and (last.id) then 
  set tableA;
run;
```

If you have multiple IDs, it's a little different.  (This works in the single ID or the multiple ID case).

```
data tableC;
merge tableB tableA;
by id;
drop PA PA_set;
length PA_n $10;
retain PA_set;
if first.id then PA_set=0;
if (from le &dateofreport. le thru) or (last.id and PA_set=0) then do;
    PA_n=PA;
    PA_set=1;
end;
rename PA_n=PA;
run;
```

I'm sure this could be done in PROC SQL, but I think it would require multiple passes through the data.  I could imagine the simplest way would be to create two datasets, one with only the max(thru) and one with the record where from le &dateofreport le thru, and union them together, and then keep the record from that set with the lowest date value (ie, either the only record, or if both keep the one that is not max(thru)).

Answer (score 0):

A perfect (and tested) SQL method is to do the following (taken from [here](http://www.listserv.uga.edu/cgi-bin/wa?A2=ind1206b&L=sas-l&P=22690)):

```
data a;
  dt='02JUN2012'd;
run;

data b;
  dt='01JUN2012'd;
  output;
  dt='03JUN2012'd;
  output;
run;

proc sql;
    select
      a.dt as dt_a,
      b.dt as dt_b,
      count(*),
      abs(a.dt-b.dt) as diff
    from a,b
    group by a.dt
    having calculated diff=min(calculated diff)
  ;
quit;
```